# Free LDAP Client for Windows?

Tags: windows, ldap

What is the best, free LDAP client for windows? It should be easy navigate through the directory and edit values. Ideally, bulk update of whole directory trees would be nice...

Comment: https://www.maxcrc.de/en/download-en/

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) from the Apache Foundation.  It's built on the eclipse platform and I've found it to be a pretty good LDAP client.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your LDAP server.  If you're using Active Directory, then the default Active Directory Users and Computers is good for a user-friendly view, whereas ADSIEdit is great for getting at the nitty gritty.  There are also good built-in command-line tools available for bulk updates/etc.

Answer (score 2):

When I am on a windows machine I normally use [LDAP Admin](http://ldapadmin.sourceforge.net/index.html) , Another option is to install [phpLDAPAdmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/) It's web based, so technically it work in windows.

Comment: +1 for the lightweight LDAP Admin, very simple and useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want access LDAP data with combination of e-directory & LDAP, Open LDAP Client is the best one. It's very easy to use and it will provide features such as like import & export data, modifying data directly using this client, removing objects(if at all you have permissions to remove)

Answer (score 0):

Another good Active Directory LDAP client is LDP[.exe]; quite essential when debugging AD problems.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I agree with mh. Use the integrated applications. Not to pick on a single answer but for example phpldapadmin has a decent amount of know exploits. Use google. Sure i bet the remote management mmc in Windows has had issues but think of it this way.

Whats better using a solution that is less popular and therefore has less penetration in the total development  cycle of the software. Only x number of people experience it and say only x^-10 review and submit data for analysis. On the other had the most common solution has a much large penetration in testing and analysis because x^1000 people use it and attack it and now x^10 review and submit data. The same ratio of review but big difference in development.

Not to mention the time between security flaws in Windows are generally patched immediately. Adobe blew everyone minds when on a known issue they decided to wait and get to it in a couple days. This proves how important large scale development is. Can you really say your solution to accessing your directory is safe then if you use anything else?

Just food for thought not bashing or flaming anything.